# Setting up Cassandra code formatter, what is options/code.style.schemes.xml used for?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to configure the Cassandra code formatter and downloaded IntelliJ-codestyle.jar from this link: https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CodeStyle

After extracting this JAR, I was able to import codestyle/Default_1_.xml into my IntelliJ project and formatting seemed to work.

However, I'm wondering what options/code.style.schemes.xml file is exactly used for? Could anyone give me an idea the purpose of this file and how it should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the exact answer for the question, however, now I know how to set up the Cassandra project in IntelliJ such that the code formatter gets configured correctly:
The info is at this link:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/source/development/ide.rst